# I'm getting "social_core.exceptions.AuthForbidden: Your credentials aren't allowed" error in Django python-social-auth/social-auth-app-django

Tags: django, authentication, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

I am using social-auth library to authenticate user with OAuth2. I can authenticate user with accessToken and check infos included in this token. The token is valid. The problem appears in line:

```
user = self.backend.do_auth(access_token=access_token)
```

And I get:

```
"social_core.exceptions.AuthForbidden: Your credentials aren't allowed"
```

This is part of my settings file:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH__OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ["localhost"]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2",
    "social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2",
    "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2")
```

I checked also secrets keys and they seem to be good, because I am able to validate token.

Thank you in advance!